# I need a shortcut

Tags: python, function

So im just trying to make a simple script that can filter emails with different domains its working great but i need a shortcut, cause i dont wana write if and elif statements many time , Can anyone tell my how to write my script with function so that will become shorter and easier.. thanks in advance ,Script is below:

```
f_location = 'C:/Users/Jack The Reaper/Desktop/mix.txt'
text = open(f_location)
good = open('C:/Users/Jack The Reaper/Desktop/good.txt','w')
for line in text:
    if '@yahoo' in line:
        yahoo = None
    elif '@gmail' in line:
        gmail = None
    elif '@yahoo' in line:
        yahoo = None
    elif '@live' in line:
        live = None
    elif '@outlook' in line:
        outlook = None
    elif '@hotmail' in line:
        hotmail = None
    elif '@aol' in line:
        aol = None
    else:
        if ' ' in line:
            good.write(line.strip(' '))
        elif '' in line:
            good.write(line.strip(''))
        else:
            good.write(line)
text.close()
good.close()
```

Comment: As you don’t use yahoo, gmail, live, outlook, or hotmail (the variables), why assign to them?

Comment: because i want other domains , i mean i want to delete yahoo , gmail etc domains from my list...(and about the variables ,, because if there is nothing under a statement then it gives me an error thats why i wrote yahoo = None

Comment: "It's working great" is an euphemism. All those comparisons starting with `@_domain_` achieve nothing and the second `if` block is overly complicated. At the moment you can reduce **the whole content** of the loop to  `good.write(line.strip(' '))`.

Comment: you can do this 3-4 lines using regex , show me sample file so i can help you out.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul https://www.sendspace.com/file/xp7fza

Comment: @JohnnyDoe ok and explain please what actually you want , what  i am getting is you want to filter out different domain that is easy but after matching those domains name what you want to do with those match ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Actually i dont want the gmail , yahoo etc domain email list on my current list .. so i want to filter out mails with other domains ,.. can you tell me the shortest way to do that .. i am a noob so dont make it complex , thanks..

Comment: @JohnnyDoe give me some time , i am trying to help you out.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul thanks brother ..

Comment: @JohnnyDoe checkout, i have provided two solutions.

Comment: @JohnnyDoe did you get the solution ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul ,, i got it , but actually im still learning python and im in the middle of course , so its complex to understand , but no problem , within some days i can understand your code ..thanks for the solution...  :-)

Comment: @JohnnyDoe    If my solution worked for you and you got your answer then you can [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `dict` for this instead of having separate variables for all the cases.

```
my_dict = {}
...
if '@yahoo' in line:
    my_dict['yahoo'] = None
```

But if you want to do the way you described in the question, you can do as done below,

```
email_domains = ['@yahoo', '@gmail', '@live', '@outlook', '@hotmail', '@aol']
for e in email_domains:
    if e in line:
        locals()[e[1:]] = None 
        #if you use dict, use the below line
        #my_dict[e[1:]] = None
```

`locals()` returns a dictionary of the current namespace. The keys in this dict are the variable names and value is the value of the variable.

So `locals()['gmail'] = None` creates a local variable named gmail(if it doesn't exist) and assigns it `None`.

Comment: what locals[e[1:]] = None menas ??

Comment: Yep, much better.

Comment: i didnt get it , can you write the whole code please

Answer (score 0):

As you stated the problem and provided the sample file :

So i have two solution : One line solution and other is detailed solution.

First let's define regex pattern and import re module

```
import re
pattern=r'.+@(?!gmail|yahoo|aol|hotmail|live|outlook).+'
```

> Now detailed version code:

```
emails=[]
with open('emails.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.finditer(pattern,line)
        for find in match:
            emails.append(find.group())

with open('result.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(emails))
```

> output in `result.txt` file :

```
nic-os9@gmx.de
angelique.charuel@sfr.fr
nannik@interia.pl
l.andrioli@freenet.de
kamil_sieminski8@o2.pl
hugo.lebrun.basket@orange.fr
```

> One line solution if you want too short:

```
with open('results.txt','w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join([find.group() for line in open('emails.txt','r') for find in re.finditer(pattern,line)]))
```

> output:

```
nic-os9@gmx.de
angelique.charuel@sfr.fr
nannik@interia.pl
l.andrioli@freenet.de
kamil_sieminski8@o2.pl
hugo.lebrun.basket@orange.fr
```

P.S : with one line solution file will not close automatically but python clear that stuff  its not a big issue (but not always) but still if you want you can use.